# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para MULTIPLICAR y después SUMAR los elementos de una LISTA?

Tags: python, lista, sum

```
cal=[5,9,7,10,6]
pond=[0.20,0.10,0.10,0.30,0.30]

i=0
calf=[]

while i<len(cal):
    n1=cal[i]*pond[i]
    n=sum(n1)
    calf.append(n)
    i=i+1
    
print(calf)
```

Lo que busco hacer es que cada elemento de la lista "cal" se multiplique con cada elemento de la lista "pond" (es decir, cal[0]*pond[0], cal[1]*pond[1],etc). Y, por último, sumarlos.

El resultado debería ser 7.399, pero no me da.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas noches otra manera tambíen utilizando la función `zip()` que toma uno o varios iterables y los empareja en forma de tupla (el primer elemento con el primero de la segunda lista) esto no retorna una lista ni una rupla, si no un dato de tipo `zip` que es un iterable y puedes hacer lo que quieras con el resultado, en este caso lo metemos en una compresión de lista y mediante `sum()` sumamos los elementos resultantes de la operación.

```
cal=[5,9,7,10,6]
pond=[0.20,0.10,0.10,0.30,0.30]
print(sum([x*y for x,y in zip(cal,pond)]))
```

Comment: Muy bueno, pero recuerda añadir una breve explicación sobre lo que hace la **función** `zip()`

Answer (score 1):

Para multiplicar dos vectores (listas) de igual largo, puedes usar comprensión de listas:

```
prod = [cal[i] * pond[i] for i in range(len(cal))]
```

Esta comprensión es un `for` que usamos para recorrer las listas en orden, multiplicando los correspondientes elementos de cada una.

Para sumar el resultado, simplemente `sum(prod)`.

**Demo**

```
cal = [5, 9, 7, 10, 6]
pond = [0.20, 0.10, 0.10, 0.30, 0.30]

prod = [cal[i] * pond[i] for i in range(len(cal))]
print("vector producto=", prod)
print("suma=", sum(prod))
```

produce:

```
vector producto= [1.0, 0.9, 0.7000000000000001, 3.0, 1.7999999999999998]
suma= 7.3999999999999995

Process finished with exit code 0
```